Navigating to a specific tab after clicking an anchor tag and once the data has been processed and added to the database
So I have a columns within a datatable called tblProducts, and an achor tag called Receive Products, and I have tabs with an Id of Producttabs , So I want to redirect to a specific tab after that achor tag called Receive Products is clicked but only after data processing and data  added to database
Please see the code of what I tried, So far it redirect to the specific tab , but the problem is that the data is not processed or  added to the database before redirecting
`
    $(document).ready(function () {
   
        try {
            $('#tblProducts').dataTable({
                "pageLength": 10,
                "autowidth": true,
                "processing": true,
                "bserverSide": true,
                "order": [[1, "desc"]],
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/TapzStore/Products/RecieveProducts",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "dataType": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { 'data': 'ProductName' },
                    { 'data': 'ProductDesc' },
                    { 'data': 'VendorName' },
                    {
                        'data': null,
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            if (row.VendorName != null) {
                                row.VendorName = row.VendorName.replace("&", "amp;")
                            }

                            return '<a class ="Recieve-link" href="/TapzStore/Products/RecieveProducts?ProductName=' + row.ProductName + '&ProductDesc=' + row.ProductDesc + '&VendorName=' + row.VendorName + '">Recieve Products</a>';
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "initComplete": function() {
                    $('#Producttabs').tabs();
                    
                    $('#tblProducts').on('click', '.Recieve-link', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $("#Producttabs").tabs("option", "active", 1);
                        console.log("im clicked")
                    });
                },
                "error": function(res) {
                    alert('Could not Recieve the product');
                }

            })
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err.stack);
        }

    })

</script>`

